# Java Trying to add 2 objects in a JFrame but only 1 is showing

Tags: java, swing, object, graphics, jframe

Im trying to make a game that one object is trying to chase the other. However in the JFrame only 1 object is showing. Can you help me please?

The main class:

```
package catchbutterfly;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Random;


public class CatchButterFly extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    Random generator = new Random();
    int x = 400, y = 800, velX = 0, velY = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Catch The ButterFly");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        Catcher t = new Catcher();
        Butterfly fly = new Butterfly();
        frame.add(t);
        frame.add(fly);


    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

The oval class that moves with keyboard inputs:

```
package catchbutterfly;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Random;

public class Catcher extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{  
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    Random generator = new Random();
    int x = 400, y = 800, velX = 0, velY = 0;
    public Catcher(){
        tm.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        System.out.println("obje catcher olustu");
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        tm.start();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(x < 0){
            velX = 0;
            x = 0;
        }
        if(x > 1366 - 50){
            velX = 0;
            x = 1366 - 50;
        }
        if(y < 0){
            velY = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        if(y > 670){
            velY = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        x = x + velX;
        y = y + velY;
        repaint();
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            velX = -4;
            velY = 0;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            velX = 0;
            velY = -4;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            velX = 4;
            velY= 0;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            velX = 0;
            velY = 4;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        velX = 0;
        velY = 0;
    }
}
```

The square class that moves x += 4 (Which doesn't show):

```
package catchbutterfly;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Butterfly extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 800, y = 500, velX = 4, velY = 4;

    public Butterfly(){
        tm.start();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        tm.start();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(x < 0 || x > 1366 - 50){
            velX = -velX;
        }
        if(y < 0 || y > 670){
            velY = -velY;
        }
        x = x + velX;
        y = y + velY;
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: frame.add(t); ---> JFrame has BorderLayout, see Oracle trail about Layout managers in AWT/Swing,

Comment: don't to use NullLayout and KeyListener for Swing JComponents

Comment: mKorbel im really a beginner in Java, I didn't understand what you've said. Can you explain it a bit more.

Comment: BorderLayout has 5th areas, you can to put only one JComponent to the one of areas (actually you uses CENTER == frame.add(t); ), have to use another area (doesn't resized proportionally in BOrderLayout) or another LayoutManager

Comment: your butterfly and catcher are two different JPanels so if you add both by using the add method without specifying any layout or area it will go to the center of JFrame and only that Jpanel will be visible that you added last, second thing how can you catch your butterfly if you are using two JPanels, you need only one Jpanel to make the game functional.

Comment: Muhammad, you're talking about 2 JPanels but i only created 1 panel, "panel".

Comment: How can i specify the layout and not add it to the center

Comment: See also [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: You create two panels. Both of your classes extend JPanel. By creating instances of Catcher and Butterfly you have therefore made two JPanels. So if there is another JPanel called panel, you've actually created 3 JPanels... But yeah...

Comment: When i delete the extends JPanels it doesnt work... I have to extend it

Comment: Your Catcher and Butterfly need not be JPanels. You should look at viable alternatives that could house this kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

As [Muhammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1966247/muhammad) and [sage88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1888503/sage88) already indicated, your butterfly and your catcher are in different panels because their classes inherit from JPanel (extends JPanel). You create a panel called panel in your main method, but this panel is not added to your frame.

The difficulty is that when both panels are added to the frame, only one is visible:

```
    frame.add(t);
    frame.add(fly);
```

You can check this by replacing the previous two lines by this block:

```
    t.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height / 2));
    t.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    fly.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height / 2));
    fly.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(t);
    frame.getContentPane().add(fly);
```

This only helps to clarify the problem, but does not solve it. Both panels get resized to share half the height of the frame and get a background color. The layout manager (object that controls how components are shown in a container) is set to a flow layout and both t & fly are added to the content pane of the frame.

As suggested before, I would change the code to have a single panel that paints both the butterfly and the catcher.

**Edit** - a simple single panel could look like this:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private Butterfly butterfly;
    private Catcher catcher;

    public MainPanel(final Butterfly butterfly, final Catcher catcher) {
        this.butterfly = butterfly;
        this.catcher = catcher;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(butterfly.x, butterfly.y, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(catcher.x, catcher.y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

You can create a MainPanel object in the CatchButterFly.main method (passing in the butterfly & catcher objects) and add it to the frame there.

Comment: Bruijn thanks for the clarification. I get what you say but the thing is i dont know how create 1 panel add both objects in it because when i delete both panels in catcher and butterfly, the code doesnt work

Comment: @MertKarakas I've added a simple example of what a single panel with drawing code for the butterfly and catcher could look like.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. Thanks for the advice. Im trying some tutorials on JPanels and Graphics. Hope I'll fix it.